# ionic 2: enable an ionic component on map click

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

How do i enable an Ionic component with click event on google map.

for Example: I have implemented a click listener on the marker which would in turn present an action sheet.

```js
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
        presentActionSheet();
    });

    var actionSheet = ActionSheet.create({
        title: 'Modify your album',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Destructive',
            role: 'destructive',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('Destructive clicked');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Archive',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('Archive clicked');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
        }]
    });

    this.nav.present(actionSheet);
}
```

but I'm getting the following error when i click on the marker

> Uncaught TypeError: this.nav.present is not a function, http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js, Line: 2265

Comment: You have a closing `}` at the very end, but not an opening `{`, so it's not clear what block of code all this is happening inside - a function, an `if` statement, a `for` loop, ...?  What is `this`?

Comment: oh sorry, the opening brace was inside a function like this.
presentActionSheet() {
  var actionSheet = ActionSheet.create({
      title: 'Modify your album',
...
..